# Reduce the gray scale bit representation of a pixel in C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap

I am sorry if the question in the header is not descriptive enough. But, basically what my problem is the following. 
I am taking Bitmap and making it gray scale. It works nice if i do not reduce the number of bits and I still use 8 bits. However, the point of the hw I have is to show how the image changes when I reduce the number of bits holding the information. In the example bellow I am reducing the binary string to 4 bits and then rebuilding the image again. The problem is that the image becomes black. I think is because the image has mostly gray values (in the 80's range) and when I am reducing the binary string I am left with black image only. It seems to me that i heave to check for lower and high gray scale values and then make the more light-gray go to white and dark gray go to black. In the end with 1 bit representation I should only have black and white image.Any idea how can i do that separation?

Thanks

```
 Bitmap bmpIn = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("c:\\test.jpg");
            var grayscaleBmp = MakeGrayscale(bmpIn);

  public Bitmap MakeGrayscale(Bitmap original)
    {
        //make an empty bitmap the same size as original
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);
        for (int i = 0; i < original.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < original.Height; j++)
            {
                //get the pixel from the original image
                Color originalColor = original.GetPixel(i, j);
                //create the grayscale version of the pixel
                int grayScale = (int)((originalColor.R * .3) + (originalColor.G * .59)
                + (originalColor.B * .11));

                //now turn it into binary and reduce the number of bits that hold information 
                byte test = (byte) grayScale;
                string binary = Convert.ToString(test, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
                string cuted = binary.Remove(4);
                var converted = Convert.ToInt32(cuted, 2);

                //create the color object
                Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(converted, converted, converted);

                //set the new image's pixel to the grayscale version
                newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
            }
        }
        return newBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would be a good TRUE black and white colormatrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746103/what-would-be-a-good-true-black-and-white-colormatrix)

Comment: No is not duplicate if you read the post carefully. I am asking completely different thing. That post only talks about black and white and not about the issue i am having.

Comment: Explain the difference and I might be convinced.

Comment: I want eventually to to land on black and white, but how would i do the intermediate steps?

Comment: Do it using [ImageAttributes.SetThreshold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6464csbe(v=vs.110).aspx), as recommended in the linked solution.  it will be much faster than looping through every pixel and calling SetPixel, which is almost never recommended.

Answer (score 0):

As mbeckish said, it is easier and much faster to use [ImageAttributes.SetThreshold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6464csbe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

One way to do it manually is to get the median value of the grayscale pixels in the image, and use that for the threshold between black and white.