# vb net save bitmap to tiff CCITT4

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, tiff

I've used the code in the question

[What would be a good TRUE black and white colormatrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746103/what-would-be-a-good-true-black-and-white-colormatrix/34037395#34037395)

and works fine.. but when I try to save in TIFF with CCITT4 compression, an error occour, invalid parameter value... If I use the LZW compression, it works fine.. I use the code:

```
Dim myImageCodecInfo As ImageCodecInfo
myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat.Tiff)

Dim myEncoderParameters As New EncoderParameters(1)
Dim myEncoderParameter As New EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4)
myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter

bmp.Save(path & "\test.tif", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters)
```

Someone can help me? Thanks..

Comment: So, you have a specific question + specific answer + code and you are not even able to understand what this code is doing and perform the required (minor) modifications?! Do you think that this is the behaviour of a programming with basic knowledge? And what is more important: have you read the help pages explaining how to use SO?! Completely off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with the project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15186/Bitonal-TIFF-Image-Converter-for-NET

bmp must be converted in bitonal 1bpp indexed otherwise the bmp.save function in CCITT4 compression format cause error.